# How can I change the value of a trackbar to 100 and also "activate" it?

Tags: c#, winforms

Example

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (checkBox2.Checked) { 
   checkBox2.Checked = false; 
   checkBox2.Click -= checkBox2_CheckedChanged; 
}
}

private void checkBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
label1.Text = "2";
}
```

So what that code does is when you check checkBox1 it'll execute the other code.
What I'd like to do is the same for a trackBar, so when I press a checkBox1 it'll activate the code in the trackBar1 to change some values.

Currently all I have managed to do is set it back to 100 (which is the maximum I've set) and it does change the slider position but nothing in the code runs.

In short, I want to assign code to a checkbox that makes it as if I have clicked and changed the value of the trackbar.

Comment: Are you using the checkbox event to change the trackBar1.Value property?

Comment: I'm using a button, but I'd imagine it's the same effect. I also plan on using a checkbox to do the value too but having no luck on it activating the code in the trackBar1

Comment: It is, but you're specifically targeting the `Value` property and wanting to have the TrackBar act as if you changed its value through the UI?

Comment: All it seems to do is set the trackbar to whatever I determine, but doesn't actually activate the code in the trackbar.

Comment: What event are you listening to on the TrackBar?

Comment: `private void trackBar1_Scroll` if that's what you're getting at. New to C# and done a tonne of googling so far, though this one I've hit a stump.

Comment: Gotcha. Check out my answer, I believe it will do what you're looking for. In future questions, include the code itself that you're having trouble with. The example you give in your question does not accurately represent your problem. Having your actual code would have made it a bit easier to diagnose. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure you're listening to the proper event that is raised when the `TrackBar` has its `Value` changed.

In your initialization code for the `TrackBar`, you need to have something along the following:

```
public Form1()
{
    // Snip
    trackBar1.ValueChanged += trackbar1_ValueChanged;
}

private void trackbar1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = trackBar1.Value.ToString();
}
```

This will setup a listener for whenever the ValueChanged event is fired for the `TrackBar` that will update a `TextBox` with the new value.

Then your checkbox event handler just needs to make sure it sets the `TrackBar.Value` property when it fires, and the `ValueChanged` event will fire for the `TrackBar` like below:

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (trackBar1.Value == 10)
    {
        trackBar1.Value = 5;
    }
    else
    {
        trackBar1.Value = 10;
    }
}
```

If the checkbox is clicked when the `TrackBar` has a value of 10, it will update the value to 5 and update the `TextBox` to read 5. If it's clicked when the value is not 10, the above happens with 10 instead.

If you manually change the `TrackBar` slider in the UI, it will update the value of the `TextBox` as you slide it around.

### Why Scroll Doesn't Work

Since you were using the `Scroll` event, you should check out the documentation for the event at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.trackbar.scroll(v=vs.110).aspx).

From the documentation:

> Occurs when either a mouse or keyboard action moves the scroll box.

This means the `Scroll` event only fires when triggered by the mouse or keyboard. Since you were programmatically setting `Value` in the code behind, the `Scroll` event would never fire.

### Why ValueChanged Does Work

So the question becomes, why does `ValueChanged` work? Again, we go to the documentation at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.trackbar.valuechanged(v=vs.110).aspx).

> Occurs when the Value property of a track bar changes, either by
>   movement of the scroll box or by manipulation in code.

Since you are looking to change it programmatically, this is the Event Handler that you want to listen to as it specifically calls out the case you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Works perfectly now

Comment: Awesome. Glad to hear it. :)